# I am trying to write a Python script to read multiple PDFs, but getting an error with the PyPDF2 initializing

Tags: python, pdf, python-idle, reader

I am new to Python coding. I cannot get out of the gate because the code is not working for PyPDF2. I have run the following command:

```
pip install PyPDF2
Collecting PyPDF2
Downloading pypdf2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
\---------------------------------------- 232.6/232.6 kB 4.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: PyPDF2
Successfully installed PyPDF2-3.0.1
```

IDLE throws this error:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

What am I missing?

I have tried reinstalling PyPDF2 using the below options:

```
pip install PyPDF2
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in

pip3 install PyPDF2
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in
```

but they did not work for me.

Comment: What IDE do you use? Does it use a virtual environment? If so, did you install it in it?

Comment: What OS are you using? If you have more than one python installed, and on Mac you like do, you likely installed PyPDF2 for one python while you run IDLE with the other python that does not have PsPDF2 installed.  There are perhaps 50 answers that address this common problem.

Comment: It looks like pip and IDLE don't agree on what version of Python to use.  pip installed it for one version, but IDLE is configured to use a different version.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show PyPDF2` and this python code `import sys; print(sys.path)`. Please edit the question and add it there; don't post it as a followup comment.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed PyPDF2-3.0.1 (the same version as you installed), however in my system `from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader` runs without errors, so I think you may have a problem with a virtual environment. If you are using PyPDF2 in a virtual environment, please install PyPDF2 in that virtual environment too.

Try starting the Python interpreter from the command line with `python3` and then run `from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader` and comment about the results of the command.

Comment: Have you actually used IDLE?  What do you consider most unfriendly about it?  (Note: Bryan's ModuleNotFoundError has nothing to do with IDLE.)